# find pair elements in 2 vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I've a pretty silly problem that I m not able to solve in an efficient way:

Assuming I have 2 vectors

```
A = [1 20];
B = [3 16 18];
```

I would like to have a matrix C containing the indices of the closer pair elements

```
C = [1 1;
     2 3];
```

This should work also in this case

```
A = [1 3];
B = [5 10];
```

where my code associates both the elements of A to the first element of B. Instead the result should be

```
C=[1 1
   2, 2];
```

The logic behind this result is:
since the first element of A is already linked with the first element of B, the second element of A should check the remaining "free" elements...

Comment: Can the vectors only be of length 2 or 3?

Comment: Find _for each element of `A`_ the closest element in `B`?

Comment: @timgeb no, they can be of any length.

Comment: @LuisMendo for the second example this doesn't work

Comment: @gabboshow Please explain how the result is obtained in the second example

Comment: I edited the question...I hope it's more clear now

Comment: @gabboshow Crystal clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find for each element of `A` the closest element in `B`:

```
[~, ii] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:).', B(:))));
C = [1:numel(A); ii].';
```

---

To find for each element of `A` the closest element among *remaining* elements of `B`: in this case a loop seems hard to avoid. You can go along the following lines:

```
C = [(1:numel(A)).' NaN(numel(A),1) ]; %'// initiallize
ind = 1:numel(B); %// list of candidate elements
for k = 1:numel(A)
    [~, m] = min(abs(A(k)-B(ind))); %// compute distances. Find closest element
    C(k,2) = ind(m); %// take note of closest
    ind = [ind(1:m-1) ind(m+1:end)]; %// remove picked element from the list
end
```